# Return jQuery deferred from error block in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to load a file via jQuery Ajax. If the first locations fails, it should try to retrieve it at another path. This basically works, the request goes to the alternative URL, but I don't get the jQuery deferred back from `loadFile()` that I need further down.

How can I make `loadFile()` always return the right deferred?

```
loadFile = function(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: u,
    error: function() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: '/otherPath/' + u
      });
    }
  });
};

loadFile('stats.xml').then(parseXml).then(...)
```

Comment: `return $.ajax(...)` inside `error` handler doesn't make sense since `error` handler isn't intended to return `Deferred` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the 2nd request inside `error:`, `loadFile()` is still returning the initial `Deferred()` which will have failed.

To be able to chain Deferreds capable of their own state, you'll want to use [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
loadFile = function(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: u
  }).then(null, function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/otherPath/' + u
    });
  });
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9sHK7/